# How not to rollback @DataJpaTest?

Tags: spring-data, spring-boot-test

In the following code

```
@DataJpaTest
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class GenreDaoJpaTest{
    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired
    private GenreRepository dao;
    ....   
}
```

when I'm adding `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` with the purpose to cancel a roolback after each test I'm getting an exception:

```
ava.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager found

    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager.getEntityManager(TestEntityManager.java:237)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager.persist(TestEntityManager.java:92)
    at ru.otus.ea.dao.GenreDaoJpaTest.init(GenreDaoJpaTest.java:38)
```

It there a way to autowire `TestEntityManager` and not to roolback transactions in tests?

Comment: Btw not sure if you know - you can also accept answers - this helps people filter out questions with accepted answers (and also rewards the helping person). .) (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: (But of course - only accept answers if the answer actually solves the problem.)

Comment: Thanks to your question I have found solution how to use DBRider @ExpectedDataset with DataJpaTest. I have problem with transaction rollback after the test method, and as a result I has no changes in db to compare with expected result. @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED) helps me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `TestEntityManager` is autowired but you are executing the `persist` call outside of a transaction.

You can autowire `TransactionTemplate`:

```java
    @Autowired
    private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;
```

And execute your DB interactions using its `execute` method:

```java
    User savedUser = transactionTemplate.execute((conn) -> {
        return testEntityManager.persist(new User("foo"));
    });
```

Also you should be aware that now you are responsible for cleanup of test DB after tests execute (which might be hard to maintain as logic grows):

```java
    @BeforeEach // just to be sure
    @AfterEach
    public void cleanup() {
        userRepository.deleteAll();
    }
```